# Scheme - value in list

Tags: scheme

I have list of lists:

((1500) (2500) (3500))

Now, I want to use the values in each list. when I do (car list), It give me (1500) - list, but I want the value 1500 (int).

How can I do it?

Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> (apply append '((1500) (2500) (3500)))
(1500 2500 3500)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `car` of the list containing 1500, which will be the value.

Something like:

```
(car (car '((1500)(2500)(3500))))
```

This suffices for the first value. There are other ways to go about it to get all the other values, as larsman pointed out.

Comment: `caar` does the same with less parens.

Answer (score 0):

```
> (map car '((1500) (2500) (3500)))
(1500 2000 3)
```